# Spring Boot + Hibernate Envers. Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I want to use Envers in my app. So I added to my pom.xml

hibernate-envers 4.2.19.Final

My hibernate version is 4.38

I didn't do anything else, tried to run the tests and it failed

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 47 more
```

Here is my application.yml:

```
spring:
profiles: default
     spring.datasource:
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/server?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_unicode_ci&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8
username: root
password: 
spring.jpa:
database: MYSQL
show-sql: true
hibernate:
    ddl-auto: validate
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

For test environment:

```
spring.datasource:
driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS \"public\"
spring.jpa:
database: H2
show-sql: true
hibernate:
    ddl-auto: validate
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    envers.default_schema: keyserver_audit
```

What additional configuration I need to do?

Comment: can you post your pom.xml? may i know why you don't use the same version for the hibernate enver? and your hibernate version is 4.3.8 right? not 4.38.

Comment: That's right. Spring Boot provides dependency versions for envers.
Using dependency without version works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Spring Data Envers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers) project which might help here. As a side bonus, it will allow you to access revisions through your repositories. You'll just need this annotation in your config:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

Also, your hibernate properties should be underneath `spring.jpa.properties` as per [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties)

Comment: I was not aware of Spring Data Envres. Do you have an example usage?